# How to query date-wise values from a table, where each date is a separate column?

Tags: sql

Let's imagine there's a table with 3 columns, which stores end of the day wallet balance for each user, for each day.

- user_id
- event_day_pst
- balance_chips_end

I wish to create buckets of users based on the wallet balance, for different days.

For a single day, I'm able to write the below code, which works fine -

```js
SELECT  
  CASE 
  WHEN balance_chips_end <= 750 THEN '< 750'
  WHEN balance_chips_end > 750  AND balance_chips_end <= 1250 THEN 'A. 750-1250'
  WHEN balance_chips_end > 1250  AND balance_chips_end <= 2750 THEN 'B. 1250-2750'
  WHEN balance_chips_end > 2750  AND balance_chips_end <= 5000 THEN 'C. 2750-5000'
  WHEN balance_chips_end > 5000  AND balance_chips_end <= 10000 THEN 'D. 5000-10000'
  WHEN balance_chips_end > 10000  AND balance_chips_end <= 20000 THEN 'E. 10000-20000'
  WHEN balance_chips_end > 20000  AND balance_chips_end <= 40000 THEN 'F. 20000-40000'
  ELSE 'G. > 40000'
  END AS balance_bucket, COUNT(user_id) AS '2022-06-11'
FROM table1 
WHERE event_day_pst = '2022-06-11'
GROUP BY balance_bucket
ORDER BY balance_bucket
;
```

However, I want to get result in from a single query, but for different days as follows (attached image) :
Attaching image as I'm not sure how to create table structure in the question

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n700H.png)

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Search for crosstab, pivot (if postgreSQL tablefunc) ...

Comment: You start by adding event_day_pst column to query and group by. Then you would cross tab (pivot) it.